# Do other languages have an equivalent to Python's Gevent?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, gevent, coroutine

I was looking into options for writing a high throughput router that can handle and route a lot of traffic with a lot of connections, and I came across [these benchmarks](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers) for options in python. Gevent clearly seemed to be the best choice for my purposes, but I am not bound to any particular language (although I do have a good deal of experience with python), and I was wondering if other languages had a library that worked in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Go](http://golang.org/) and [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/) have very similar ideas of 'green threads' or lightweight threads.